# Alexa Skill not accepting intents when not opened with LaunchRequest

Tags: javascript, node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I'm working on an Alexa Skill that asks you a question and then waits for your response.

I have her doing this by setting should end session to false.

```
//I'm using node.js 6.10 btw
this.handler.response.response.shouldEndSession = false;
```

And I have an intent that is set up for responses. One utterance is just a slot and I have some more with prefixes like "My answer is.. ". Up until this point it worked fine but now I've decided to add DynamoDB integration so that I can have longer breaks between questions. I have an intent for requesting the next question which also initialises variables from session attributes.

My problem is that if the session ends and the user reopens it with this intent, alexa doesn't seem to accept any intents without telling her name and the skills name even though she has the microphone open (the leds are on) ...

For example I can tell my answer like this "Alexa, tell MySkill the anwer is [answer]" instead of just saying "[answer]".

She handles what I say as if I was giving her orders outside of the skill. I don't know if this is clear enough but for example if the answer was 'stop' instead of saying that is correct/incorrect she would say 'theres is no music playing' or something like that or if it was something she could not handle like 'a cat' instead of (again) saying correct/incorrect or at least execute my skills fallback intent she says her default 'I don't know that' text.

Any idea?

**EDIT:**

Here is my code for responding the get next question intent.

```
    //add event handler. we only read the question when users press 2 echo buttons. This is to ensure the buttons are awake and connected.
    //obj is 'this' in the event handler, this code is moved to a function
    var dir = wakeupDirective;
    //.. add gadget ids to directive..
    obj.response._addDirective(dir);
    obj.response.speak("Press your echo buttons when you are ready for the next one.");
    obj.emit(":responseReady");
```

Other function to handle the event when 2 buttons are pressed

```
    var handleInput = function(){
      //.. other events
      this.attributes.status = -1;
      qind = this.attributes.qind;
      questionQueue = this.attributes.questions;
      tellNextQuestion(this,"");
    }

function tellNextQuestion(obj,text,emit = true){
    text += "The next question is..." + questionQueue[qind].question + "<audio src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/ask-soundlibrary/foley/amzn_sfx_rhythmic_ticking_30s_01.mp3'/>";
    //add input handler for 'buzz in'
    obj.response._addDirective(buttonPressDirective);
    delete obj.handler.response.response.shouldEndSession;
    obj.response.speak(text);
    if(emit)
        obj.emit(':responseReady');
}
```

And here is the code that runs when somebody buzzez in (this is the same no matter if there was a 'break' or not.

```
var g = events[i].inputEvents[0].gadgetId;
waitingAnswer = true;
teamBuzzedIn = t1color;

if(this.attributes.teams[t2color].gid == g){
    teamBuzzedIn = t2color;
}

this.response.speak("Go ahead "+ teamBuzzedIn + " team. I am waiting for your answer.");
this.response.listen("You have 8 more seconds to answer.");
this.handler.response.response.shouldEndSession = false;
this.emit(':responseReady');
```

Comment: Let me see if I have this straight... You're saying that when the session ends (the blue light goes off,) you can no longer pick up the dialog where you left off? This is just the way Alexa is programmed. As soon as a session ends the user of your skill will have to reopen your skill by triggering the "Alexa" wake word and then asking her to interact with your skill by using the invocation name. Unfortunately there's not really anything you can do to bypass that.

Comment: Not exactly. I’m saying, that my session ends and I don’t say alexa open myskill but instead alexa ask ymskill for the next question (I have an intent for this). She Opens a new session, my code loads the data from dynamo, she tells me the question, but I cant answer without sayin alexa, tell myskill the answer is... however If the session does not end once during the game (so the user does not have to reopen asking for the next question) this works.

Comment: Ahh I got it now. That's a much more complicated problem and requires a bit more context from your code to try to figure out. Could you add the code you used for responding to the 'get next question' intent?

Comment: Added the code.